# What would someone charge for digging 4 inches of dirt/much?

Tags: lawn

I need to have 4 inches of dirt and mulch mix dug up across my small approximant 400 sq ft front yard and move gutter drain...I want to know a rough price estimate so I'm not being taken advantage off any advice price knowledge or involved labor would be helpful as there are no wrong replies only shared knowledge and advice

Comment: Asking for quotes/costs is not really the purpose of Gardening & Landscape SE. The reason is that it is dependent on a number of factors, and is likely to become quickly outdated limiting the use of any answers.

Comment: Whilst this is not appropriate for the site, for future reference to asking further questions,please give your geographic location. This question and many (indeed most) others cannot be answered without this information.

Comment: Yep, not the place to ask this - but here's  piece of  advice, get 3 or 4 different quotes from different  people/companies.

Comment: What is the minimum wage in your area?  You could easily find some well raised young man or woman to dig this out in less than an hour.  $20 bucks?  A professional digger with insurance and bonding probably $50 an hour.  400 square feet and 2" equals 2 1/2 cubic yards.  Think of one cubic yard as a washing machine full of soil or whatever.  400 sq. ft. divided by 81 gives you the answer in cubic yards necessary to remove and order and install 4" of gravel, soil or whatever.  So 400 divided by 81 is 5 divided by 2 gives you the amount you need removed and also the amount to replace.

Comment: How fast do you think someone could scrape 2" out of that 400 sq. ft. area to fill 2 1/2 washing machines?  Shoot, even half an hour would be plenty.  When you hire professionals you have to remember that professionals pay for insurance and bonding.  If they hit a water line (doubtful) or break a window by an errant stone, they have insurance to cover the damage.  If they get hurt, they have L & I to pay for injuries.  Protecting any home owner insurance you have.  Worth the extra money in my opinion.  It is a bit of a risk to hire muscle with no backing but that is up to you to weigh.

Comment: Why I got the inches messed up...400 divided by 81 gives you 4" of material.  How long would it take to fill 5 washers with 5 yards of soil?  Definitely at least an hour, perhaps an hour and one half.  This requires no more than a shovel and wheel barrow.  No heavy equipment fees for 'move in'...you should have some where on your property to dump the soil, this will save dump fees.  Plant beds, vegetable garden?  Somewhere close for less wheel barrow time.  One person, 2 hours max, for two people, plan on at least an hour. Usually a minimum time fee.  Kids? 3 to 4 hours. No phones allowed!